# Dialogue Parser

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-split

I have a dialogue file that looks like so:

```
CHARACTER       MOOD         PROMPT RESPONSE  TEXT      LEVEL         PATH
```

As you can see, everything is separated by spaces. The trick comes in when 
`PROMPT RESPONSE  TEXT` is supposed to be one header (read together) all heading groups are separated by no more than two spaces while each heading is separated by 3+ spaces. What I am trying to do is take this line and add it into an array much like this:

```
array(4) => {
    [0]=> string(9) "CHARACTER",
    [1]=> string(4) "MOOD",
    [2]=> string(21) "PROMPT RESPONSE  TEXT",
    [3]=> string(5) "LEVEL",
    [4]=> string(4) "PATH"
}
```

I am trying to use `preg_split` with the following regexp `/\s\s\s+/` but it does nothing more than yield an empty array. I assume that the regexp would split if on any amount of spaces equal to or greater than 3. Is there something more to this?

Comment: Try using `/\s{3,}/` and ensure that the regexp is in single quotes (`'`) rather than double quotes (`"`) else PHP may try and translate `\s` itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following, this looks for whitespace ( at **least** `3` times )

```
$results = preg_split('/\s{3,}/', $text);
var_dump($results);
```

Output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=> string(9) "CHARACTER"
  [1]=> string(4) "MOOD"
  [2]=> string(21) "PROMPT RESPONSE  TEXT"
  [3]=> string(5) "LEVEL"
  [4]=> string(4) "PATH"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to have the overhead of loading the regex engine you could use this

```
<?php

$t = 'CHARACTER       MOOD         PROMPT RESPONSE  TEXT      LEVEL         PATH';

$u = explode('   ',$t);

print_r($u);

$new_u = array();
foreach( $u as $key => $val) {
    if ($val != '') {
        $new_u[] = trim($val);
    }
}
print_r($new_u);
```

Results

```
Array
(
    [0] => CHARACTER
    [1] =>
    [2] =>  MOOD
    [3] =>
    [4] =>
    [5] => PROMPT RESPONSE  TEXT
    [6] =>
    [7] => LEVEL
    [8] =>
    [9] =>
    [10] => PATH
)
Array
(
    [0] => CHARACTER
    [1] => MOOD
    [2] => PROMPT RESPONSE  TEXT
    [3] => LEVEL
    [4] => PATH
)
```

Comment: While the above did solve my issue I ended going with this solution due to it being faster.